# Adding a cookie in Shopify

Tags: javascript, php, shopify

I am trying to add a value in cookie in my store. Javascript is not an option because the content of the cookie needs to be invisible on the client-side page source.

In a PHP server it's done using a code like this:

```
<?php
$cookie_name = "PHPsecret";
$cookie_value = "The secret";
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); // 86400 = 1 day
?>
```

Can someone please help me acheive this in Shopify? Even if it can be done with some work-around trick such as manipulating the cart attribiute etc. it's okay. Let me know how.

Much appreciated.

Comment: Cookies aren't secret

Comment: By secret I mean  invisible in page source. Now edited.

Comment: What ever you pass to the client, is not a secret, you cant make anything *invisible*. You have a couple of options for *invisible*, store server-side in session or store in db.

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain a bit more on store server-side in session?

Comment: server side session wont work in shopify. Maybe you can store the value as cart attribute. Either way you have to use javascript.

Comment: Have you fond a solution for this, @Matty ? What if you create your own encryption and decryption system in liquid. Meaning, the value that gets passed to the cookie is just a bunch of characters that won't make sense client side, but your liquid code will "know" what to do with it. Then, whatever you're passing will be "invisible."

Answer (score 0):

I needed to pass a Shopify variable, `{{ cart.item_count }}` to a subdomain using a cookie. For me, adding this in Javascript at the bottom of `theme.liquid` did the trick:

```
<script>
  var nowCart = new Date();
  var timeCart = nowCart.getTime();
  var expireTimeCart = timeCart + 1000*36000;
  nowCart.setTime(expireTimeCart); // " + nowCart.toUTCString() + "
  document.cookie = "_count={{ cart.item_count }};domain=.example.com;expires=;SameSite=none;Secure=true";
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

In Shopify Liquid, there is to the best of my knowledge no way to "hide" a cookie. In fact, anyone who knows how to open their dev tools would be able to read your cookie either way...does it really need to stay a secret (consider adding it to a liquid variable instead)?

The next best option I can recommend is to put your Javascript into a separate .js file in the assets folder of your `theme.liquid` and include it in your theme like so, `{{ "cookie-code.js" | asset_url | script_tag }}`.

Once again, if the user can open dev tools, they could still read your cookie or look at your javascript file. Maybe clarify in more detail what exactly it is that you're trying to achieve?